# How admin can change data in SQL Server in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to add a controller for the `ApplicationUser.cs` so that when a admin is logged in, they have the ability to view, edit, delete any records from the `dbo.AspNetUsers` table however I think I'm doing it wrong.

```
 <form asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="ActiveUser" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@user.Email" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Active</button>
        </form>
```

Admin Controller :

```
  [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult ActiveUser() { return View(); }


    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ActiveUser(ApplicationUser Model)
    {
         var active =_userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Email == Model.Email);
        if (active != null)
        {
            active.IsActive = true;
            using (var transaction = _application.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {

                    await _application.SaveChangesAsync();
                    transaction.Commit();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _ = (ex.Message);
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    return View("Er");
                }
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

but I think Submit button linked to wrong form post because when I debug active is null! and no changes in my SQL Server. How to manage it?

Comment: Is Model.Email null, that is do you receive the data from the form? Does the DB contain the user in question? Also consider wrapping code in ModelState.IsValid which will tell you if any model errors have been added to ModelState.

Comment: It seems no such method(`_userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault()`) in UserManager.How did you define it?And please check your Email is null or not.What about change `asp-for="@user.Email"` to `asp-for="Email"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add, delete and modify the users and roles in `AspNetUsers` you must use the `UserManager` and `RoleManager` services. Do not try to modify the entities directly using the `DbContext`.

So to create a user calll the `UserManager.CreateAsync()` method.
To save changes to a user call `UserManager.UpdateAsync()`

Example - To find a User by email address, change a property then save the change:

```cs
var currentUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
currentUser.IsActive = true;
await _userManager.UpdateAsync(currentUser);
```

The same applies for roles that users are in. Use the `RoleManager` service to add and delete roles.

```cs
if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName))
{
    await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
}
await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(currentUser, roleName);
```

[Microsoft docs with some examples of updating users and roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#add-custom-user-data-to-the-identity-db)

Comment: I did as you said but it shows me this Error " ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'email')"

Comment: This is just example code. You might try Model.Email instead of email.